# Footnotemark in chapter title (memoir)

Tags: footnotes, memoir

I want to add footnote to chapter title in memoir. It works as expected with numbered chapters (`\chapter`), but shows lots of errors in unnumbered chapter (`\chapter*`). MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{this fails\footnotemark{}}
\chapter[this works fine]{this works fine\footnotemark{}}
\end{document}
```

There are more than 100 errors, but first is `The control sequence marked <to be read again> should not appear between \csname and \endcsname.`

What can be a solution?

Comment: Protect it: `\protect\footnotemark`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Can you post it as answer - so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Honestly, I'm not 100% sure why this happens. But with stuff like this the issue can often be resolved if one protects the problematic question.

In this case `\protect\footnotemark{}` seems to work.